# LISP local/global variable assignment

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

If we define a function something like

```
(defun foo(x)
  (setf x somevalue))
```

Is `x` defined as a local variable or global? using setf/q is setting the value to be global.
if it is global can anyone tell me how to define a local variable in lisp other than `let`?

Thanks!

Consider the following example

```
(let ((x 0)) 
  (defun foo (y) 
    (when (equal x 0) (setq x y)) 
    (when (< x y) (setq x y))
    x))
```

when I am giving some input to `foo` like `(foo 2)` , it is returning 2 and if we execute the function again with `(foo 1)` it still returns 2 and `(foo 3)` returns 3.This is what i actually want it do.But the question is how is this possible, because if I try to access the variable `x` outside the function from the clisp terminal, I am unable to.If I am accessing the function again, it seems to retain the previous value of `x`.

thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To draw a parallel to other languages like C, C++, Java or Python what your code changes is a "local variable" even if this is not a wording that a Lisper would use (the wording in Lisp parlance would be a local "binding").

You can create local variables by using function parameters like your example does, or using some standard forms like:

- `(let ((x 12)) ...)`
- `(do ((x 0 (1+ i))) ...)`
- `(dotimes (x 10) ...)`
- `(loop for x from 0 to 10 do ...)`

On the other hand it is possible that in your implementation all local variables are created using parameters and other forms simply are macros expanding to that. For example:

```
(let ((x 10)) ...)
```

is equivalent to

```
(funcall (lambda (x) ...) 10)
```

Note also that indeed reading your code fragment it's possible that `x` is in a sense a "global variable" because it could have been declared special:

```
(defvar x 12)
;; ==> x

(defun bar ()
  (format t "The value of x is ~a" x))
;; ==> bar

(defun foo (x)
  (bar))
;; ==> foo

(foo 42)
The value of x is 42
;; ==> NIL

x
;; ==> 12
```

If you declare a variable "special" using `(defvar ...)` it will be handled differently: it's like every time you use it as a parameter or you use it in a `(let ..)` form what the code will do is saving the current value, using the new provided value and then restoring the value after you exit the function or `let`.

So those variables are both "global" (because outer functions can see them) but also local (because after your function or let terminates the previous value will be restored).

The standard convention is to name special variables with "earmuffs" i.e. with an asterisk both at the start and at the end of the name like:

```
(defvar *x* 12)
```

This helps who reads your code to understand that the variable is special. Note that however this is not mandated by the language and any name can be used for a special variable.

There is nothing similar to special variables in C, C++, Java or Python.

One last note about `setq` and `setf`. Things are a bit tricky here because you need to understand lower levels of Lisp to see why `setq` is needed. If you are using Common Lisp then you should simply forget about `setq` and always use `setf`.

`setf` is a macro that will expand to `setq` when needed (however also `setq` can change into `setf` when needed (symbol macros) and this is where things may get confusing for a newbie).

Your last example is a case of a "closure". When you define a function (either named or unnamed with a `(lambda ...)` form) the function can "capture" the variables that are visible and use them later. A simpler case often shown is the "adder":

```
(defun adder (x)
  (lambda (y) (incf x y)))
```

this function returns a function that will keep adding the passed value to an internal totalizer:

```
(let ((f (adder 10)))
  (print (funcall f 3))
  (print (funcall f 9))
  (print (funcall f 11)))
```

the output will be 13 (10 + 3), 22 (13 + 9) and 33 (22 + 11).

The anonymous function "captured" the local variable `x` and can use it even after exiting the `adder` function. In languages like C, C++ or Java a local variable cannot survive when you exit the scope that defined the variable.

C++11 has unnamed functions, but still variables cannot be captured and survive the scope (they can be copied to local variables of the unnamed function, but this is not the same thing).

Comment: thanks a lot!!!
can you help me with this code which is making me band my head to a wall:
((let (x nil)
   (defun (y)

Comment: @user1473253: that is not valid lisp code (parenthesis are not even balanced): are you talking about having a `(defun ...)` form inside a `(let ...)` form? If you have questions about common lisp the IRC channel `#lisp` can be helpful for that (http://webchat.freenode.net)

Comment: i have edited the question a bit with one more example.Can you please take a look at it?Thank you!sorry for the trouble

Comment: Thank you.I will do some googling on `lisp closure`.Thanks for the help again :)

Comment: so in other words,for lisp, all "local variables" are always in  the idiom of `((x) => {/*yay, I has a local binding */})(x)`?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `x` is local to the function, so `setf` or `setq`ing it only changes the local variable `x`.

To answer the second part of your question, there is another way to define a local variable other than let:

```
(funcall (lambda (var1 var2...)
           ... use var1 var2 ...)-
   val1 val2 ...)
```

In fact, `defun` could be implemented as

```
`(setf (symbol-function ,name) (lambda ,args ,@body))
```

though all the implementations I've checked do more than that.

Also, the `symbol-function` place allows you to do this:

```
(setf (symbol-function '+) (function -))
```

though that's generally a bad idea.

### Your second question

What's happening there is that `x` is local to the scope that contains the `defun`. It's **not** a global variable. What you're doing with that `defun` is creating a closure that "captures" all the lexically-scoped (not created with `defvar`/`defparameter`) variables in the surrounding scopes and holds on to them for the future. If you want to inspect the value of `x`, add another function

```
(defun get-x () x)
```

inside the `let`. To put it another way, `x` is local to the `let` that the function is in. The situation you've provided is similar to:

```
(let ((x 3))
    (print x)
    (let ((y 7))
        (print (list x y))
        (setf x y))
    (print x))
```

except the inner `let` is replaced by a `defun` (which is a `lambda`).

Answer (score 0):

In your code `x` is a parameter to the `f` function and thus local to the function. The call to `setf` does not create new variable, but simply sets the value of the existing local variable `x`. Using `setq` instead of `setf` would behave the same.