# Can you create local variables without a `let`?

Tags: variables, scope, global-variables, common-lisp, local-variables

## eg1 - using a `let`

```cl
(defun demo1 ()
 (let ((a 1)
       (b 2))
  ; these print fine
  (print a)
  (print b)))

(demo1)
; these get "no value" errors, as expected
(print a)
(print b)
```

output:

```cl
1 
2 *** - EVAL: variable A has no value
```

## eg2 - without a `let`, the variables escape

(this is *very* surprising for anyone used to more modern scope-rules like eg ruby's)

```cl
(defun demo2 ()
 (setf a 1)
 (setf b 2)
 ; these print fine
 (print a)
 (print b))

(demo2)
; these escape, and also print with no error!
(print a)
(print b)
```

output:

```cl
1 
2 
1 
2
```

**how can you make them *not* escape?**
i monkey'd around with `setq` and `defvar`
(which were mentioned in the only results i could find by looking for documentation on "local variables")
but no joy at all

## eg3 - trying to use a macro

(
this is the practical problem i wanted to solve in the first place --
the syntax of `let` forces you to use extra layers of parens,
and wrap up the entire function body in the outermost layer,
which just makes it harder to read and write for no reason
(since the overwhelmingly most common use case for `let`
always includes the entire function body and nothing else),
so i wanted to make a `with` macro instead
)

```cl
(defmacro with (&rest list-of-pairs)
 (loop for (name value) in list-of-pairs
    do  `(setf ,name ,value)    ;A
  ; do  (setf name value)       ;B
  ; (i tried both A and B)
 ))

(defun demo3 ()
 (with (a 1)
       (b 2))
 ; this gets a "no value" error when called
 (print a)
 (print b))

(demo3)
; it never even gets to this point cuz of the above error
(print a)
(print b)
```

output:

```cl
*** - PROGN: variable A has no value
```

**how can you get the variables to escape into the function scope and not beyond?**

[
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333590/lisp-local-global-variable-assignment) asks

> can anyone tell me how to define a local variable in lisp other than let?

but none of the answers were helpful to me
]

## EDIT-TO-ADD eg4

thinking about the way the `loop` macro works
(from the point of view of someone *calling* it without understanding its internals, i mean)...
well, look:

```cl
(loop for i from 1 to 5 
 do (print i))
```

i don't know yet what the definition of `loop` looks like,
but it's abstractly something like this, right?:

```cl
(defmacro loop ([args somehow,
                 including the `sexpr`
                 which goes after the `do` keyword in the macro call])
 [other stuff]
 do ([sexpr])
 [other stuff])
```

*(i'm focusing on the `do` keyword as an example just because the syntax of the call is relatively simple.)*

so what i actually need to do is make my own `my-defun` macro
and include a `with` keyword,
right?

something like this:

```cl
(defmacro my-defun ([args somehow,
                     including a `paired-list-of-names-and-values`
                     to go after a `with` keyword in the macro call])
 (let
  ([paired-list-of-names-and-values])
  ([function body])))

(my-defun demo4 ()
 with (
 (a 1)
 (b 2)
 )
 ; this should print
 (print a)
 (print b))

(demo4)
; this should get a "no value" error
(print a)
(print b)
```

**am i on the right track here?**

**if so, where do i go from here?**

like, what are some simple, straight-forward macro definitions i can look at to induce how they work?
or something like that

Comment: "the syntax of `let` forces you to use extra layers of parens,
and wrap up the entire function body in the outermost layer,
which just makes it harder to read and write for no reason" -- You're missing an important point: Wrapping them in parentheses leaves no doubt about their scope. If your functions get that long that "the extra layer of parens" is a problem, then you're doing something wrong ;)

Comment: hmmm... i find that argument very unconvincing in this case? i figured it out, and posted it as an answer to my own question. i put a mindif of using both ways at the end, to help eyeball how worth the trouble it was (you can copy them each into a buffer and flip back and forth quickly to really visually highlight the differences), and... i still think it makes sense, ya know? there's no doubt about the scope, cuz it just wraps `let` and goes to the end of the `my-defun` call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[EDIT:
i just realized that i messed up on the arguement handling,
**so my "solution" is broken**
if there aren't at least three lists given to `my-defun` after its parameter list.

i put the (i think) **actual working solution at the end.**
]

i actually figured this out!

it's not too hard at all,
even for a newb.

(
i mean,
i wouldn't be surprised if horrible things would happen if one actually tried to use it in "real code",
because edge-cases or something,
but it's a working proof-of-concept
)

anyway, here's a definition of the `my-defun` macro,
working as i described in `eg4` in my question:

(
please nobody edit the weird formatting --
i realize it's non-standard,
but it really helps newbs read difficult new stuff.
i mean,
if another newb like me ever reads this,
i think it'll help them significantly.
)

```cl
(defmacro my-defun (name params withsymbol withlist &body body)
 (cond
   ((equal withsymbol 'with)    
                                ; (print 'withsymbol_set_to_)   ;diagnostic
                                ; (print withsymbol)            ;diagnostic
                                ; (print 'withlist_set_to_)     ;diagnostic
                                ; (print withlist)              ;diagnostic
                                ; (print                        ;diagnostic
                                 `(defun ,name ,params          
                                   (let ,withlist               
                                    (progn ,@body)              
                                   )                            
                                  )                             
                                ; )                             ;diagnostic
   )                            
   (t                           
                                ; (print 'withsymbol_not_set_to_with_but_)  ;diagnostic
                                ; (print withsymbol)                        ;diagnostic
                                ; (print 'withlist_set_to_)                 ;diagnostic
                                ; (print withlist)                          ;diagnostic
                                ; (print                                    ;diagnostic
                                 `(defun ,name ,params                      
                                    (progn ,withsymbol ,withlist ,@body)    
                                  )                                         
                                ; )                                         ;diagnostic

   )
 )
)
```

## first test, with a `with`:

```cl
(my-defun demo4 (x)
 with (
  (a 1)
  (b 2)
 )
 ; this prints!
 (print a)
 (print b)
 (print x)
)
(demo4 "hi")
; this correctly gets a "no value" error!
(print a)
(print b)
(print x)
```

output:

```cl
1 
2 
"hi"
```

output with diagnostic lines uncommented:

```cl
WITHSYMBOL_SET_TO_ 
WITH 
WITHLIST_SET_TO_ 
((A 1) (B 2)) 
(DEFUN DEMO4 (X) (LET ((A 1) (B 2)) (PROGN (PRINT A) (PRINT B) (PRINT X)))) 
1 
2 
"hi"
```

## second test, with no `with`:

(so it acts exactly like a normal `defun`)

```cl
(my-defun demo4 (x)
 ; (this stuff also prints)
 (print "i am not the withsymbol")
 (print "this is not the withlist")
 ; this prints!
 (print "symbol 'a would have no value")
 (print "symbol 'b would have no value")
 (print x)
)

(demo4 "hi")
; this correctly gets a "no value" error!
'(print a)
'(print b)
'(print x)
```

output:

```cl
"i am not the withsymbol" 
"this is not the withlist" 
"symbol 'a would have no value" 
"symbol 'b would have no value" 
"hi"
```

output with diagnostic lines uncommented:

```cl
WITHSYMBOL_NOT_SET_TO_WITH_BUT_ 
(PRINT "i am not the withsymbol") 
WITHLIST_SET_TO_ 
(PRINT "this is not the withlist") 
(DEFUN DEMO4 (X)
 (PROGN (PRINT "i am not the withsymbol") (PRINT "this is not the withlist") (PRINT "symbol 'a would have no value")
  (PRINT "symbol 'b would have no value") (PRINT X))) 
"i am not the withsymbol" 
"this is not the withlist" 
"symbol 'a would have no value" 
"symbol 'b would have no value" 
"hi"
```

## minimally different examples:

using `defun` with `let`
and using `my-defun` with `with`
(just wanted to eyeball to what extent the result looks worth the trouble xD)

```cl
(   defun demo (x)
 (let (
       (a 1)
       (b 2)
      )
  (print a)
  (print b)
  (print x)
 )
)

(my-defun demo (x)
 with (
       (a 1)
       (b 2)
      )
 (print a)
 (print b)
 (print x)
)
```

## ACTUALLY WORKING SOLUTION (I HOPE):

```cl
(defmacro fun (name params &rest rest)
 (let (
       (withsymbol  (car rest))
       (withlist    (car (cdr rest)))
       (body        (cdr (cdr rest)))
      )
  ; (p withsymbol   )   ;;debug
  ; (p withlist     )   ;;debug
  ; (p body         )   ;;debug
  (cond
   ((equal withsymbol 'with)    
                                ; (print 'BRANCH_A)     ;;debug
                                ; (print                ;;debug
                                 `(defun ,name ,params  
                                   (let* ,withlist      
                                    (progn ,@body)      
                                   )                    
                                  )                     
                                ; )                     ;;debug
   )                            
   (t                           
                                ; (print 'BRANCH_B)     ;;debug
                                ; (print                ;;debug
                                 `(defun ,name ,params  
                                    (progn ,@rest)      
                                  )                     
                                ; )                     ;;debug

   )
  )
 )
)
;; for debugging
(defmacro p (symbol)
 `(format t "~A ~A~%" ',symbol ,symbol)
)
```

although that was the earliest working version of the code,
so maybe i messed it up without noticing by renaming variables incompletely or something.

the most recent code that i actually just tested is more complicated:

```cl
;; used in debug
(defmacro p (symbol)
 `(format t "~A ~A~%" ',symbol ,symbol))

(defmacro mac-or-fun (which-one name params rest)
 (let (
       (withsymbol  (car rest))
       (withlist    (car (cdr rest)))
       (body        (cdr (cdr rest)))
      )
  ; (p withsymbol   )   ;;debug
  ; (p withlist     )   ;;debug
  ; (p body         )   ;;debug
  (cond
   ((equal withsymbol 'with)    
                                ; (print 'BRANCH_A)         ;;debug
                                ; (print                    ;;debug
                                 `(,which-one ,name ,params 
                                   (let* ,withlist          
                                    (progn ,@body)          
                                   )                        
                                  )                         
                                ; )                         ;;debug
   )                            
   ((equal withsymbol 'omwith)  
                                ; (print 'BRANCH_A)         ;;debug
                                ; (print                    ;;debug
                                 `(,which-one ,name ,params 
                                   (omlet ,withlist         
                                    (progn ,@body)          
                                   )                        
                                  )                         
                                ; )                         ;;debug
   )                            
   (t                           
                                ; (print 'BRANCH_B)         ;;debug
                                ; (print                    ;;debug
                                 `(,which-one ,name ,params 
                                    (progn ,@rest)          
                                  )                         
                                ; )                         ;;debug

   )
  )
 )
)
(defmacro fun (name params &rest rest)
  `(mac-or-fun defun ,name ,params ,rest))
(defmacro mac (name params &rest rest)
  `(mac-or-fun defmacro ,name ,params ,rest))


;; for use in tests
(defun ps (&rest stringlist)
     (format t "~A~%" (eval `(concatenate 'string ,@stringlist))))
(defparameter *vs-use-count* 0)
(defmacro vs (&rest title)
 (setf *vs-use-count* (+ 1 *vs-use-count*))
 (ps "

SECTION " (write-to-string *vs-use-count*) " " (write-to-string title)  " -"
 )
)

;;;tests
(progn

(vs fun works with "with")
(fun f ()
     with ((a 1))
     (print a)
     )
(f)
(vs fun works with "nil")
(fun f ()
     ()
     )
(print(f))

(vs original fun test with "with")
(fun demo4 (x)
 with (
  (a 1)
  (b 2)
 )
 ; this prints!
 (print a)
 (print b)
 (print x)
)
(demo4 "hi")
; these would correctly gets a "no value" error!
'(print a)
'(print b)
'(print x)

(vs original fun test with no "with")
(fun demo4 (x)
 ; (this stuff also prints)
 (print "i am not the withsymbol")
 (print "this is not the withlist")
 ; this prints!
 (print "symbol 'a would have no value")
 (print "symbol 'b would have no value")
 (print x)
)

(demo4 "hi")
; these would correctly gets a "no value" error!
'(print a)
'(print b)
'(print x)




(vs mac works with "with")
(mac m ()
     with ((a 1))
     (print a)
     )
(m)

(vs mac works with "nil")
(mac m ()
     ()
     )
(print(m))
)


;;; more stuff,
;;; leading up to the macro `omlet`,
;;; which is used in `mac-or-fun`
(fun pair-up (l)
 with (
  (a        (car l)         )
  (b        (car (cdr l))   )
  (l-past-b (cdr (cdr l))   )
 )
 (cond
  (
   (equal 2 (length l))
   (list l)
  )
  (t
   (cons (list a b) (pair-up l-past-b))
  )
 )
)

(fun crack-1 (eggs)
    with (
        (paired-list    (pair-up eggs))
        (paired-list    (loop for (k v) in paired-list collect `(,k ',v)))
    )
    paired-list
)
(fun crack-2 (eggs)
    with (
        (key-name           (car eggs))
        (value-name         (car (cdr eggs)))
        (eggs               (cdr (cdr eggs)))
        (paired-list        (pair-up eggs))
        (keys-list          (loop for pair in paired-list collect (first pair)))
        (values-list        (loop for pair in paired-list collect (second pair)))
        (key-name-keys      (list key-name keys-list))
        (value-name-values  (list value-name values-list))
        (paired-list        (append paired-list (list key-name-keys value-name-values)))
        (paired-list        (loop for (k v) in paired-list collect `(,k ',v)))
    )
    paired-list
)
(fun crack (eggs)
    (if
        (and
            (equal '- (car eggs))
            (oddp (length eggs))
        )
        (crack-2 (cdr eggs))
        (crack-1 eggs)
    )
)
(mac omlet (eggs &body body)
    with ((to-let (crack eggs)))
    `(let ,to-let (progn ,@body))
)
(mac lemego (&rest eggs)
    with ((to-set (crack eggs)))
    (loop for (name value) in to-set
        do (eval `(setf ,name ,value))
    )
)


;;; more tests
(progn

(vs omlet 1)
(omlet (
    x   a
    y   b
    z   c
)
    (print  x   )
    (print  y   )
    (print  z   )
)

(vs omlet 2)
(omlet (
    - names digits
    one     1
    two     2
    three   3
)
    (print  one     )
    (print  two     )
    (print  three   )
    (print  names   )
    (print  digits  )
)


(vs fun with omwith 1)
(fun f ()
omwith (
    x   a
    y   b
    z   c
)
    (print  x   )
    (print  y   )
    (print  z   )
)
(f)

(vs fun with omwith 2)
(fun f ()
omwith (
    - names digits
    one     1
    two     2
    three   3
)
    (print  one     )
    (print  two     )
    (print  three   )
    (print  names   )
    (print  digits  )
)
(f)


(vs lemego 1)
(lemego
x   a
y   b
z   c
)
(print  x   )
(print  y   )
(print  z   )


(vs lemego 2)
(lemego
- names digits
one     1
two     2
three   3
)
(print  one     )
(print  two     )
(print  three   )
(print  names   )
(print  digits  )
)
```

Answer (score 10):

**Simple rule: `SETF` or `SETQ` do not create variables. Neither local nor global. They just set variables.**

Never set an undefined variable using `SETQ` and `SETF`. This is Common Lisp, not `Ruby`.

It also does not help to create `SETF` forms with a macro. Why should this make a difference?

**Defining local variables**

If you look into the Common Lisp standard, there are a zillion constructs which allow to define local variables: `DEFUN`, `DEFMETHOD`, `LET`, `LET*`, `DO`, `DOTIMES`, `FLET`, `LABELS`, `LAMBDA`, `DESTRUCTURING-BIND`, `MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND`, ...

**Local variables in functions**

If you look at functions, the argument list for functions allows you to define local variables:

- required   argument
- optional   argument
- keyword    argument
- auxilliary argument
- rest       argument

You can define functions with `LAMBDA`, `DEFUN`, ...

Example for `&optional`:

```
((lambda (a &optional (b 20))
   ... ; a and b are known here inside the function
 )
 10)   ; we don't need to pass an arg for `b`, optional!
```

Example for `&aux`:

```
((lambda (a &aux (b (+ a 20)))
   ... ; a and b are known here inside the function
 )
 10)   ; we CAN't pass an arg for `b`, auxiliary!
```

**Variables in LOOP**

You don't need to guess what the LOOP macro does, you can ask Lisp to show you - here using LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 27 > (pprint (macroexpand '(loop for i from 1 to 5 
                                         do (print i))))

(BLOCK NIL
  (MACROLET ((LOOP-FINISH () '(GO #:|end-loop-82961|)))
    (LET ((I 1)
          (#:|to-82964| 5)
          (#:|by-82965| 1))
      (TAGBODY (PROGN (SYSTEM::INTERNAL-IF (OR (> I #:|to-82964|))
                        (GO #:|end-loop-82961|)))
       #:|begin-loop-82960|
       NIL
       (PRINT I)
       (PROGN
         (LET ((#:|temp-82966| (+ I #:|by-82965|)))
           (SETQ I #:|temp-82966|))
         (SYSTEM::INTERNAL-IF (OR (> I #:|to-82964|))
           (GO #:|end-loop-82961|)))
       (GO #:|begin-loop-82960|)
       #:|end-loop-82961|
       (RETURN-FROM NIL NIL)))))
```

As you can see it expands into a form, where the variable `i` is introduced by a `LET`. It also expands into a form, which makes use of a *goto* construct.

As you can see, you can implement a very fancy syntax - like the LOOP syntax - in Lisp. But the implementation of LOOP is large and non-trivial. Nothing for a beginner.

Comment: so, in my eg3, i wanna keep the definition of `demo3` and all the same, and change only the definition of the `with` macro so that it works (ie gets the same output as eg1). i can't understand from your answer -- are you saying that **i should be able to use the info you gave me to do that?** or are you saying that **it's just not possible?** >:? (i'm *very* new to lisp. just did the [elmart](http://art2.ph-freiburg.de/Lisp-Course) and [lisptutorjr](http://alarm.cti.depaul.edu/lisptutor/login) tutorials, then got the info on how to write macros from a friend who knows barely more than i do...)

Comment: @Owen_R: use LET or the function lambda list. Don't fight against the language.

Comment: so just to confirm, that's a definite "it's just not possible"?

Comment: @Owen_R: You can define your own personal programming language on top of Lisp. But that's not a topic for a beginner.

Comment: right, of course, thanks anyway... hmm, so now i'm wondering about common-lisp's scope rules. like i said, they seem *really* weird from a modern perspective. suspiciously awkward first-impression. do they have some trade-off advantages? or is that awkwardness just an artifact of the language's age or something...?

Comment: i mean like, "it was made before the right way do to it had become obvious, and then it couldn't be fixed without breaking stuff" or something? it seems really weird, because clearly there *is* a built-in idea of the scope of a function, cuz otherwise *parameters* couldn't do their variable-shadowing thing, right...?

Comment: if it can properly shadow and unshadow variable definitions for parameters passed in to a function, why not for definitions set inside the function? how is it so that it works like that?

Comment: @Owen_R: Common Lisp is designed for efficient compilation with the possibility for fast execution. It is also designed to have only a small core set of minimal built-in language elements (the special operators). Another design rule: language elements should best enclose the code where they have effects. This makes processing much easier. Introducing variables in the middle of a sequence of forms is not very Lispy. It makes code harder to read, to process and to compile.

Comment: ahhh, i think that may've helped trigger an insight, thanks! i edited the question to add an `eg4`. can you tell me if i'm on the right track?

Comment: i figured it out! added my own answer with a working `my-defun` macro... like i said, i wouldn't be surprised if something horrible could happen if one tried to use it in real code, but yeah, yay anyway ^^... i guess thanks for not actually answering my question, cuz it was funner to figure it out xD

Answer (score 2):

I happen to like how bindings are introduced in Lisp, and I miss it in other languages.
However, I do not attempt to change them to my liking.
Instead, I follow the particular idioms of other languages.
In a comment, you ask:

> are you saying that I should be able to use the info you game me to do that, or are you saying that it's just not possible?

In fact, Rainer Joswig is telling you that you *should not* do that, for the same reason that you do not introduce `BEGIN` and `END` macros in C code to replace braces: just work with the existing language instead of directly trying to "fix" it.

By the way, please understand that the existing design of `LET` is *not* an accident, and work as expected. The fact that is looks weird to you "from a modern perspective" (see OCaml/F#) does not imply that it is wrong or badly designed. I don't know what you mean with the following comment:

> it can properly shadow and unshadow variable definition for parameters passed in to a function

... but I can tell you that it does not make much sense as-is.
Please consult [Online Tutorials for programming Common Lisp](http://www.cliki.net/Online%20Tutorial) to have a better view of Lisp before trying to modify it.

Comment: The example is wrong. :-) Variable definition constructs in LOOP have to be all before the LOOP body. You can't mix body and variable declarations. So, no more WITH after the first DO. Check the syntax of LOOP. The sequence of clauses for LOOP is: name* variable* main*.

Comment: Some implementations complain about the syntax error. ;-)

Comment: "just work with the existing language instead of directly trying to "fix" it."  -- that... is the *absolute opposite* of the advertised "lisp philosophy" xD. anyway, i *did* get it to work ; see my own answer to the question. (but i did in the end appreciate what @RainerJoswig meant... the solution i finally figured out, working *within* the simple rules of the language as given, i think make more sense than how i originally thought it should work with my pre-existing biases all like "WHY U NO RUBY SCOPE RULES?" xD)

Comment: (besides, even if it "shouldn't be done", figuring out how to do it rather than giving up is obviously the right choice for a good learner, right)

Answer (score 0):

Rainer did cover this above, but perhaps not addressed specifically to your example: the &optional parameter for function definition (defun or lambda) seems to be exactly what you are looking for (and indeed is implemented as a macro around let, I believe).

```
(defun do-stuff (&optional (a 10) (b 20))
  (print a)
  (print b))

(do-stuff)
10
20
20 <-- return value as last form evaluated in defun

(print a) --> ERROR; it has not escaped.
```

If you just wanted to try implementing the macro, good on you!

Comment: not my dv, but why `&optional`? I'd rather go with `&aux`: `(defun do-stuff (&aux a b) (setf a 1) (setf b 2) (print a) (print b))` etc., to mirror the OP code.

Comment: I probaby deserve the dv for bumping a super old thread, I notice now that I'm awake.

I guess it's hard to tell what the desired functionality is from this (toy) example, but if the goal is printing stuff, that makes the 'things you print' direct parameters, not auxiliary variables. Either works, though, and I don't have a real preference other than I typically choose optional. I think the macro difference is something like LET vs LET*, so the order of evaluation might determine which is preferred.

Comment: `optional` implies you sometimes call the function this way, sometimes the other. so if you're not going to call it, there't no reason to have optional args, it's just confusing. inner vars are `&aux`. personally I dislike optional in all cases, because most often than not it is used to call self when really an inner "worker" should be defined and called, to express recursion. so again, optional args add confusion.